# How can I get int result from web python sql query?

Tags: python, sql, web.py

My code is as follows. My question is, how can I get the int result from the query?

```
import web 
db = web.database(...)
rs = db.query('select max(id) from tablename')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query method returns a list. Then you can access your calculated column by using an alias. If you don't want to use an alias, then I think you can do `rs[0]['max(id)']`

```
rs = db.query('select max(id) as max_value from tablename')
print rs[0].max_value
```

This is based on the example used in the `web.py` docs: http://webpy.org/cookbook/query

Here is the example from the link:

```
import web

db = web.database(dbn='postgres', db='mydata', user='dbuser', pw='')

results = db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users FROM users")
print results[0].total_users # -> prints number of entries in 'users' table
```